# How do I know what controller an HTML element belongs to, just by looking at the output (the elements panel in dev tools)?

Tags: angularjs

If I look at an HTML element in a complex angularJS application, and it has basic directive that evaluates an expression, e.g.

```
<li ng-class="{active: active}"></li>
```

How can I tell what controller the 'active' property belongs to, just by looking at the markup?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the `active` variable doesn't belong to a controller, it belongs to a scope. Scopes use prototype inheritance, so the variable could belong to any scope.

There are multiple directives that create scopes, so it might be hard to realize which scope it belongs to.

If you want to use a controller property, define an alias like `ng-controller"myCtrl as alias"` (should be unique), then, you can use the propertyas `alias.myProperty` and the alias will let you know inmediately which controller it belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome Developer Console you can grap the element using angular.element($0) method and some useful methods are
Controller : **angular.element($0).controller()** 
Scope :  **angular.element($0).scope()**

**Chorme Extension : AngularJS Batarang** 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en

Comment: You should explain that `$0` stands for last element selected in developer tools